# SQL Server, finding the SUM of a foreign key column

Tags: sql-server

I currently have 3 tables.

Table 1: customers

```
 id(PK)      name         surname
 ----------------------------------

  1          name1         surname1  
  2          name2         surname2
  3          name3         surname3
  4          name4         surname4
```

Table 2: sales

```
 id(FK)   game(FK)   price(FK)
 -----------------------------

  1          1          1  
  2          4          4
  3          4          4
  4          3          3
  1          3          3
  2          3          3
  3          2          2
```

Table 3: stock

```
 id(FK)   game      price
 -----------------------------

  1       game1      20  
  2       game2      30
  3       game3      40
  4       game4      50
```

What I'm looking to do is find the sum of all the sales listed in the sales table (table 2).

So far, I can display a table showing how much money each game has made in total but cannot get the overall total of sales to display.

I have tried

```
select sum(sales.price)
from sold
```

However, this is just calculating the sum of the foreign key (in this case it would be 20). However, I want it to display 270.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the stock and sales tables to get the correct price of each of the items sold.

```
Select sum(stock.price) from sales 
inner join stock on sales.game = stock.id
```